# How to undo merge of master branch?

Tags: git, github, version-control, merge, git-branch

I'm new Github so please forgive what may seem like an obvious question.  I have an `Experimentation` branch which is 24 commits ahead of the `master` branch.

Following this tutorial, I merged the `master` branch with the `Experimentation` branch like so:

```
git checkout master
git merge Experimentation
```

(There were no merge conflicts.)

But then I realized that merging the two branches would not keep the commit history of the `Experimentation` branch and what I really wanted was to do a rebase (in order to keep the commit history of the `Experimentation` branch).

So my question is: **how do I undo the merge of the `master` branch?**

I've already tried:

```
$ git branch
      Experimentation
    * master
      pod-attempt

$ git merge --abort
      fatal: There is no merge to abort (MERGE_HEAD missing).
```

The "fatal" message confused me b/c I thought I *did* merge the `master` branch.

Comment: git merge abort works only during the merge not after. In example, when you have a conflict to resolve, you're in the middle of a merge and you could abort it.

Comment: @alexscott oh okay thank you for the clarification!

Answer (score 22, accepted):

There is no ongoing `merge` pending so git is supposed to show you,

```
fatal: There is no merge to abort (MERGE_HEAD missing).
```

Now if you want to go back to previous state (state before you merged), try

```
$ git branch
      Experimentation
    * master
      pod-attempt
$ git reset --hard HEAD~24
```

You are done!

Comment: I get an error: **fatal: ambiguous argument 'HEAD~c927e642': unknown revision or path not in the working tree.
Use '--' to separate paths from revisions, like this:
'git <command> [<revision>...] -- [<file>...]'**

Comment: you cannot use HEAD~c927e642 as reference. Use only c927e642 instead.  Fot example, git reset --hard c927e642

Comment: What exactly does the number `24` do?

Comment: @aexl its the number of commit you want to go ahead from head. OP wants to go ahead 24 so its mentioned in example, you can try any valid cl count instead.

Comment: Thanks a lot.  It Works, but without ~24